# how to get updated state inside useIdleTimer.onIdle callback?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-state

Have this pretty simple logic where if there is a logged in user and he has been idle for a certain amount of time he should be shown an inactivity modal

```
const { user } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth)

const [isInactiveModalActive, setIsInactiveModalActive] = useState(false)

const handleOnIdle = () => {
    user && setIsInactiveModalActive(true)
}

useIdleTimer({
    onIdle: handleOnIdle,
    timeout: 1000,
    crossTab: true,
    debounce: 500,
})
```

The problem is that no matter what I do inside of "handleOnIdle" the user is always null, I have confirmed that it should not be nulled by seeing what it is in the dev tools and by console logging inside of a useEffect

I have tried a few "hacks" Wrapping everything in a useCallback, creating a local state version of the user. but nothing seems to work.

How can I make sure I always have access to the latest user inside "handleOnIdle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is the basic stale closure over the selected `user` state value in the `handleOnIdle` callback. I suspect `useIdleTimer` just caches the initially passed `onIdle` handler and doesn't check for updates, and if this is the case then no matter of re-enclosing a `user` value in the `handleOnIdle` callback, or memoizing it, can fix this. Without seeing the `useIdleTimer` hook's implementation to see what/how it handles its argument changing a very trivial solution is to cache the `user` value in a React ref and access this in the idle handler. The ref is closed over in callback scope, but the current value it holds can be mutated and accessed at any point in the future.

Example:

```js
const { user } = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth);
const userRef = React.useRef(user);

const [isInactiveModalActive, setIsInactiveModalActive] = useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  userRef.current = user;
}, [user]);

const handleOnIdle = () => {
  if (userRef.current) {
    setIsInactiveModalActive(true);
  }
};

useIdleTimer({
  onIdle: handleOnIdle,
  timeout: 1000,
  crossTab: true,
  debounce: 500,
});
```